# Direct2d CreateBitmapfromWICBitmap giving assert error within ATL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, com, atl, direct2d

I have a simple function that loads a Png file and returns it as a ID2D1Bitmap. But when it tries to call the CreateBitmapfromWicBitmap function, it gives a debug assert error. The funny thing is that I first made an imageload function in a seperate project, and it works fine in there. Both of these functions have the same code, while the second one is giving errors.

Here's the erroring code:

```
ID2D1Bitmap* Wnd::LoadPng(LPCWSTR Path) {
    CComPtr<IWICBitmapDecoder> pDecoder;
    CComPtr<IWICBitmapFrameDecode> pFrame;
    CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> pBit;
    CComPtr<IWICFormatConverter> pConv;
    HRESULT Hr;

    Hr = m_pWICFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(Path,NULL,GENERIC_READ,WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand,&pDecoder);

    if (SUCCEEDED(Hr)) {
        Hr = m_pWICFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&pConv);
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(Hr)) {
        Hr = pDecoder->GetFrame(0,&pFrame);
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(Hr)) {
        Hr = pConv->Initialize(pFrame,GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,WICBitmapDitherTypeNone,0,0.f,WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom);
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(Hr)) {
        Hr = m_pRT->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(pConv,0,&pBit);
    }
    return pBit;
}
```

The error happens in atlcomcli.h at line 182 in function _NoAddRefReleaseOnCComPtr.

I double-checked all headers and libraries and they're the same in both projects (With some extra headers in the second project).

Here's the code that WORKS:

```
        CComPtr<IWICFormatConverter> Conv;
        m_pWICFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&Conv);
        CComPtr<IWICBitmapFrameDecode> Frame;
        m_pDecoder->GetFrame(0,&Frame);
        Frame->GetSize(&W,&H);
        Conv->Initialize(Frame,GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,WICBitmapDitherTypeNone,0,0.f,WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom);
        CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> Bit;
        Hr = m_pRT->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(Conv,0,&Bit);
        m_pBitmap.push_back(Bit);
```

BitmapDecoder is predefined here, but it's exactly the same as in the first snippet.

------------------------------- FIXED ----------------------------

Third time I forgot to call the init function for my rendertarget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assertion failure warns you that you are trying to "use" a `NULL` interface pointer through `CComPtr` template. You should look up on the call stack which exactly line of your code you are at, and what variable holds NULL pointer which you expect to be non-NULL. Or otherwise just step through your code with debugger.

Comment: Whoa...third time I forgot to call the init function for my rendertarget.